# Which method is faster and gives better efficiency?

Tags: mysql, arrays, node.js, performance, filter

**Environment :** NodeJS , Websocket , MySQL , CentOS Server

**What i exactly want ?**

This is my MySQL database table "users_history"

```
+-----+---------+------------------+
| ID  | UserID  |     History      |
+-----+---------+------------------+
|  1  |      1  | Login            |
|  2  |      2  | Login            |
|  3  |      1  | Added new record |
|  4  |      2  | Added new record |
|  5  |      1  | Added new record |
|  6  |      3  | Login            |
|  7  |      3  | Added new record |
|  8  |      3  | Added new record |
|  9  |      1  | Added new record |
| 10  |      2  | Deleted recoed   |
+-----+---------+------------------+
```

And i want to send their history to their Websocket connection according to their UserID.

**Problem ?**

I have two methods, but i don't know which one is faster and provides better efficiency ?

**Method 1**

Selecting data from database for each user.

**Example :**

> **For user 1 :**
>   Select  * from history where UserID = 1
>
> **For user 2 :** 
>   Select  * from history where UserID = 2
>
> **For user 3 :** 
>   Select  * from history where UserID = 3

and send their data to each user according to their UserID

.

**Method 2**

Select all data in one query and store in a array then filter data for each UserID and send to user according to their UserID.

**Example :**

> Select  * from history where UserID IN (1,2,3)

Comment: I believe that at a time, you will need to get history of a single user only ? If yes, why do you need to fetch history of all other users. Minimize your query output size.. in most scenarios, that is the major performance bottleneck.

Comment: Hello @MadhurBhaiya , i need history of all connected users on Websocket server at a time.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Since he is using real-time client communication (websockets) he would have the id of every user that is currently connected, and I believe he is sending each of them all their data at the same time. In that case he should use method #2 to minimize round-trips to the database.

Comment: Well if I needed to know the answer to this question I would try BOTH METHOD and place a start and stop timer round the queries. Or test the queries using something like WorkBench that gives you a timing as part of each query

Comment: @Paulpro What senario would suggest that ALL users would want this information all at the same time. And, I suppose without actually asking for it

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not about what the users want, it's about what the OP wants :P

Comment: Do you have an index on `UserID`? That is the most important thing and will make both of these queries an order of magnitude faster if you don't have one already.

Comment: In general method #2 will be faster (and the difference will grow as the number of users does) especially if you use a single database connection for all the queries in method #1.

Comment: @Paulpro no i have no index on UserID.

Comment: yes Method#1 have single connection for all queries

Comment: *"yes Method#1 have single connection for all queries"* @ShubhamPanchal every (web/node.js) user will make its own connection per request Important is that reuse the connection within a request so you don't have to reconnect...

Comment: *" i have no index on UserID"* Then method 2 will be most likely slightly faster like @Paulpro also already said  because only one query needs to be parsed/optimized/opening the table/permission checked/statistics (indexes checking) see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f6d92/4) then you can see the differences... Method 2 will be most slightly faster  because all query methods will require a FULL scan annyway which might be cached or not.. Question is a bit to hard to answer.

Comment: Offtopic: Also for your query `Select * from history where UserID IN (1,2,3)` using the filter `WHERE UserID  >= 1 AND UserID  <= 3` would make more sense especially when you have indexes as MySQL optimizer should see it can do a range scan.

Answer (score -1):

A database cannot "send" data.  Instead, you `SELECT` the data you want.  Either the intended recipient can initiate the `SELECT` and get the results back.  Or you can have some other agent that does the `SELECT` and somehow "sends" it to the 'user', perhaps by email.